How to tell whether a COM dll contains type library or not?
I failed to register a COM dll(regsvr32 some.dll) possibly because the dll does not contain the type lib for the COM server. I would like to know how to check if the dll contains a type lib or not.

regsvr32 just calls an exported DLL entry point "DllRegisterServer" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/olectl/nf-olectl-dllregisterserver). If this function is not exported you will get one type of error. If it's exported, what it really does depends on the developer who coded it. It's not necessary a registry registration and/or a typelib registration (although standard tooling like Visual Studio ATL usually do it), it depends. What error do you get exactly?

@SimonMourier Yes, I debugged the dll and found it failed at LoadTypeLibEx so I wonder the typelib is missing in the dll.

What error do you get exactly? The typelib is usually a Win32 resource of the .dll or .exe, but it could be external too.
